# What is the ground state of the Hubbard model for $t = 0$?

Tags: ground-state, bose-hubbard-model

I am new to the Hubbard model and it is not clear to me how we go to the so called 'atomic limit' where $t = 0$. So we only have a $U > 0$ term in the Hamiltonian. This should be a trivial problem to solve from what I have heard but I am unable to see what is the ground state energy of an $N$ lattice Hubbard model in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ill try and give an answer. I am thinking you have a fixed number of electrons. The Hilbert space of the model is $4^L$ with L the number of sites in your system, since you can have either zero electrons on each site or you can have one of spin up or spin down or you can have both.

Your $H = U \sum_r c^{\dagger}_{r,\uparrow} c_{r,\uparrow} c^{\dagger}_{r,\downarrow} c_{r,\downarrow}$ where $c_{r,\sigma}$ annihilates an electron at site $r$ with spin $\sigma$. This is just the Hubbard model with $t=0$.

From this we now start from the vacuum state with no electrons and you would find $H |0> = 0|0>$, so the energy of this state is 0. If you create only one electron on either site you'll get zero also. If you ever put two electrons on the same site the state will then have $U$ energy. If you had N site that are doubly occupied you'll have $N\times U$ energy. So the ground state would be to have as few pairs as possible. If you had a classical half-filled band so there are $L$ electrons, one for each site the ground state would be one electron on each site having zero energy and each pair would cost $U$ energy. This ground state is very degenerate though, I would think $2^L$ times since there are no spin-interactions so you can choose many ways to place your L electrons.